# Can C# files contain file-level summary comments?

Tags: c#

E.g.

Foo.cs:

```
using System;

/// <summary>
/// This file contains Foo and Bar-related things.
/// </summary>

namespace Xyz {


class FooThing {
}

}
```

Does C# support such XMLDoc comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, XML document comments can only appear on specific types of elements, as described [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3260k4x7):

> In source code files, documentation comments that precede the following can be processed and added to the XML file:
>
> Such user-defined types as a class, delegate, or interface
>
> Such members as a field, event, property, or method

If you place a file-level XMLDoc-style comment in your file, it will be appended to the next  class or other element that happens to appear. Certain documentation tools, like Sandcastle, provide a way to add namespace-level XMLDoc comments but they generally appear in a separate file.

Of course, you can use *non* XMLDoc-style comments in each file, e.g. a copyright header or similar, by just using standard /* */ style comment blocks.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [/doc documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3260k4x7.aspx), no, that is not supported.

> In source code files, documentation comments that precede the following can be processed and added to the XML file:
>
> - Such user-defined types as a class, delegate, or interface
> - Such members as a field, event, property, or method